# Concatenate a list of lists into a string printed on separate lines

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

I have a list of lists of strings such that:

```
decipher = [['###>>?', '@@@###', '*&*...', '@@&#&#'], ['###>>?', '@@@###', '*&*...', '@@@###'], ['###>>?', '@@@###', '*&*...', '@@@###'], ['###>>?', '@@@###', '*&*...', '@@@###']]
```

I need to concatenate items with the same indeces from each list to print on the same line, each subsequent set of identically indexed items have to print on a new line:

```
###>>?###>>?###>>?###>>?            
@@@###@@@###@@@###@@@###
*&*...*&*...*&*...*&*...
@@&#&#@@&#&#@@&#&#@@&#&#
```

How can I accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to try yourself and come with problems. Plz don't ask "do it for me !!!"

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+transpose+a+list+in+python

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary You might want to give `lmgtfy` a try ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A simple one line solution would be:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(''.join(i) for i in zip(*decipher))

###>>?###>>?###>>?###>>?
@@@###@@@###@@@###@@@###
*&*...*&*...*&*...*&*...
@@&#&#@@@###@@@###@@@###
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
for col in range(len(decipher[0])):
    out = ''
    for row in range(len(decipher)):
        out += decipher[row][col]
    print(out)

###>>?###>>?###>>?###>>?
@@@###@@@###@@@###@@@###
*&*...*&*...*&*...*&*...
@@&#&#@@@###@@@###@@@###
```